# popup.js can`t receive messages from background Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, sendmessage

I try this:

**background.js**

receive messages from popup.js (work fine)

```
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
            console.log('chrome.runtime.onMessage');
            console.log(request);
            if (request&&request.method&&request.action) {
                if($.isFunction(getLr()[request.method][request.action])) {
                    sendResponse(getLr()[request.method][request.action](request.data?request.data:undefined));
                } else {
                    sendResponse(getLr()[request.method][request.action]);
                }
            }
        });
```

send data to popup.js (**don't work**)

```
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tabs){
        for(let t in tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[t].id, $.extend({}, {method: method}, data), callback);
        }
    });
```

**popup.js**

send to background script (work fine)

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: method, action: action, data: data}, callback);
```

receive from background (**don't work**)

```
window.onload = function () {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log('chrome.runtime.onMessage');
    });
};
```

what wrong?

Comment: Don't use `window.onload`. When content script is run, the `onload` event has probably been triggered already.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko what to use?

Comment: Nothing. From your last block of code eliminate the first and the last line. Keep just `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener...`

Comment: @IvánNokonoko still don`t work

Comment: Why do you use `$.isFunction()`? Is jQuery defined?

Comment: @guest271314 if i remove `window.onload = function () {` jQuery  = undefiend

Comment: To send a message to popup window use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` instead of `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`. The popup is not a Chrome tab.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko thanks.